# Java -- Iterations not working

Tags: java, iteration

I am doing a Java game that's like Cows and Bulls. But instead of displaying "Cow" and "Bull" it displays "MOO" or "moo." A 4 digit number is generated and the user can guess it. For each digit correctly specified (same number, same position), a "MOO" is displayed on the screen. For each digit that is guessed that has the same number, but wrong position a "moo" is displayed. I'm having trouble doing my method that returns how many "moo's" are returned.

```
public int getLittleMooCount(int guess)
{
    int count = 0;
    String guessString = Integer.toString(guess);
    String randomValueString = Integer.toString(randomValue);

    // Pads the number with zero if less than 4 digits, so length is always 4
    while(guessString.length() < 4)
    {
        guessString = "0" + guessString;
    }

    while(randomValueString.length() < 4)
    {
        randomValueString = "0" + randomValueString;
    }

    // checking to see if positions EXACTLY match. If so, it would return a MOO (the getBigMoo
    // Count is in my other method)
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (guessString.charAt(i) == randomValueString.charAt(i))
        {
            randomValueString = randomValueString.replace(randomValueString.charAt(i), 'X');
            guessString = guessString.replace(guessString.charAt(i), 'O');
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (guessString.charAt(j) == randomValueString.charAt(i))
            {
                count++;
                randomValueString = randomValueString.replace(randomValueString.charAt(i), 'X');
                guessString = guessString.replace(guessString.charAt(j), 'O');
            }

        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

1. Inputs for Testing

   1. 0011
   2. 2233
   3. 4455
   4. 6677
   5. 8899
   6. 1234
   7. 5678
   8. 9090

And the results w/ Random Number of 5509

1. 1 moo = correct
2. nothing = correct
3. 1 moo = WRONG! Should be two moo's.
4. nothing = correct
5. 1 MOO = correct
6. nothing = correct
7. 1 MOO = correct
8. 2 moo = correct

It seems like it will work for some numbers, but for others, there is always one test data that is wrong. Obviously, something is wrong, but I tried everything and it's frustrating! I can post another example if it would be helpful.

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT: Alright, I changed it to a character array, and now it doesn't do anything. I could of swore I did this right.

```
int count = 0;
    String guessString = Integer.toString(guess);
    String randomValueString = Integer.toString(randomValue);

    char [] randomValueCharacter = randomValueString.toCharArray();
    char [] guessCharacter = guessString.toCharArray();


    while(guessString.length() < 4)
    {
        guessString = "0" + guessString;
    }

    while(randomValueString.length() < 4)
    {
        randomValueString = "0" + randomValueString;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (guessString.charAt(i) == randomValueString.charAt(i))
        {
            randomValueCharacter[i] = 'X';
            guessCharacter[i] = 'O';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (guessString.charAt(j) == randomValueString.charAt(i))
            {
                count++;
                randomValueCharacter[i] = 'X';
                guessCharacter[j] = 'O';
            }

        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of String.replace().
This function does not replace the character at a specific position as you assume, it replaces all apperances of the given character! So after the first 5 is found, both 5's are replaced by an x.

JavaDoc

> public String replace(char oldChar,
>                char newChar) Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar. If
>   the character oldChar does not occur in the character sequence
>   represented by this String object, then a reference to this String
>   object is returned. Otherwise, a new String object is created that
>   represents a character sequence identical to the character sequence
>   represented by this String object, except that every occurrence of
>   oldChar is replaced by an occurrence of newChar.
>
> Examples:
>
> "mesquite in your cellar".replace('e', 'o')
>            returns "mosquito in your collar"  "the war of baronets".replace('r', 'y')
>            returns "the way of bayonets"  "sparring with a purple porpoise".replace('p', 't')
>            returns "starring with a turtle tortoise"  "JonL".replace('q', 'x') returns "JonL" (no change)   Parameters:
>   oldChar - the old character. newChar - the new character. Returns: a
>   string derived from this string by replacing every occurrence of
>   oldChar with newChar.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

You could use an integer array instead.

---

Try this

```
    int count = 0;
    String guessString = Integer.toString(4455);
    String randomValueString = Integer.toString(5509);

    char [] randomValueCharacter = randomValueString.toCharArray();
    char [] guessCharacter = guessString.toCharArray();


    while(guessString.length() < 4)
    {
        guessString = "0" + guessString;
    }

    while(randomValueString.length() < 4)
    {
        randomValueString = "0" + randomValueString;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (guessCharacter[i] == randomValueCharacter[i])
        {
            randomValueCharacter[i] = 'X';
            guessCharacter[i] = 'O';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (guessCharacter[j] == randomValueCharacter[i])
            {
                count++;
                randomValueCharacter[i] = 'X';
                guessCharacter[j] = 'O';
            }

        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: change charAt(i) to guessChar[i] etc.

Comment: I changed them all to that (well, from the string variable to the character variable and then the () to the []. Works fine, except when I test it when the random number is 1675, and I put 0011, it doesn't display anything when it should display one moo.

Comment: Another example is random number is 5122 and guess is 2233, and it displays a MOO and two "moo's" and it shouldn't display a big one.